# How to give color for x values and y values in linear regression model?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

```
x = 10 * np.random.rand(100)
y = 3 * x + np.random.randn(100)
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 8))
plt.scatter(x, y);
```

The color is giving blue color for plot. How to give red color for the y values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must either have a constant color, or map the color to some value. If you want to map the color to the values of `y`

```
 plt.scatter(x, y c=y)
```

Otherwise if you need a constant color, you could

```
 plt.scatter(x, y, c='r')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
x = 10 * np.random.rand(100)
y = 3 * x + np.random.randn(100)
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 8))
# c='r' gives red color
plt.scatter(x, y, c='r');
```